# Stop WLP from writing System.out into messages.log

Tags: logging, websphere, websphere-liberty, websphere-8

I have a WebSphere application which uses some third party libraries which write HTTP traffic into `System.out` / `PrintWriter`. WLP by default writes those messages into the messages.log file. I want to disable this as there may be sensible data in the HTTP traffic which I don't want to be logged.

[In the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html?cp=SS7K4U_8.5.5) I only see the setting for the console.log LogLevel, but not for the messages.log. Is there a way to set the LogLevel for this file or to just disable it?

Comment: Have you tried adding `<logging traceSpecification="*=off"/>` element to the `server.xml`? If the framework is using standard JUL logging maybe you would be able to define lit like `com.your.third.party.packages.*=off`

Comment: I just solved the situation by changing the logging configuration of the third party library that caused the concerns. But as I think that's not alway a viable solution I'll leave the question up.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of configuring Liberty to not store System.out messages in the messages.log file.

I see from your comments above that you have found a solution for this particular case.  For others reading this, if you were really stuck you could write your own PrintStream and use `System.setOut(printStream)` to filter what actually goes to stdout.  Your PrintStream could implement a filter at the start of all print methods before delegating to the Liberty printStream.

```
PrintStream libertyPrintStream = System.out;
PrintStream myPrintStream = new MyPrintStream(libertyPrintStream);
System.setOut(myPrintStream);
```